# Server log in Issue

Tags: spring, struts

am facing the issue when am trying to access the server for the second time.

Scenario :

1 ) First there are two servers

2 ) I have logged in the first server and proceed to second server for the completion of the movement or processing.

3 ) once i completed the process i return back to the first server.

4 ) i havn't logged out from the first server still, am proceeding with the second movement again and trying to access the second server again.

5 ) right now am getting error : 500

Why does this happen??
Could anyone help me out with this??

Note : Am traversing from spring security to struts and again return back to spring security

Comment: which server, what log, how you returning, why you returning ;)?

Comment: this is the requirement, server is the remote server.

Comment: Returning by redirect URL that is passed from the first server to access the first server again

Comment: You get the issue??

Comment: Might be worth checking the logs to see what the 500 error is, no?

Comment: I had checked it :) a very strange thing is there is nothing shown on server logs